# "Object doesn't support method" error when extending Element.prototype in IE8

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype, extend, chain

I understand that IE8 supports extension of the `Element` object. I tried a simple example, and it works in Google Chrome but not in IE8. Here is my code, [**and here is a jsfiddle to see my code**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJsbZ/):

**HTML**

```
<div id='test'>Hi</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Element.prototype.test = function(){
  alert('yup');
}

document.getElementById('test').test();
```

**Errors**

```
//jsfiddle.net => Object doesn't support property or method 'test'
//local test => 'Element' is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

Ok as for the local error, it seems that IE8 didn't like my `<!DOCTYPE>` tag. So I found another one. =p IE8 is very strict on things like that. If an element isn't valid HTML, IE8 won't pick it up in things such as `document.getElementsByTagName()`.

Comment: Well if I remember correctly <IE8 do not support it, IE9+ does. I believe IE8 supports it only like `document.getElementById('test').prototype.foo = ...`

Comment: you shouldn't use the word "test" twice in two different contexts.

Comment: @alfred, I think it's fine here since this code will never be in production, and it's 5 lines. ;)

Comment: I don't know if jquery is normalizing things or what, but if I include jquery on the fiddle, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/eJsbZ/2/

Comment: @epascarello, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900%28VS.85%29.aspx#custom), IE8 supports extension of the `Element` object.

Comment: In fact, if you just remove the MooTools library it seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/eJsbZ/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MooTools overrides the baseline `Element`.

Check out

```
var e = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(e instanceof Element);
```

with MooTools on it returns false, with anything but MooTools it should return true.